# Filter by window function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have defined the following DB model:

```
User(Base):
    points = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    rank = query_expression()
```

And I would like to run the following query:

```
rank_expr = func.row_number().over(order_by=desc(User.points))
db.query(User)
    .options(with_expression(User.rank, rank_expr))
    .filter(rank_expr < 10)
    .all()
```

However, running this query I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.WindowingError: window functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 3: WHERE row_number() OVER (ORDER BY users.points DESC) ...
```

I cannot use `.filter(User.rank < 10)` as `User.rank` seems to be always `None`(as also documented here under 'caveats': https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/columns.html#orm-queryguide-with-expression).

I have tried to implement the rank column as a hybrid property but also got the no-window-functions-in-where error.

I have also tried a subquery:

```
sq = db.query(User)
    .options(with_expression(User.rank, rank_expr))
    .subquery()
db.query(sq)
    .filter(rank_expr < 10)
    .all()
```

but again the same error.

I dont want to use a construct such as:

```
User(Base):
    points = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

rank_expr = func.row_number().over(order_by=desc(User.points))
db.query(User)
    .add_columns(rank_expr)
    .filter(rank_expr)
    .all()
```

because it returns tuples of User and rank which can't be automatically mapped to my pydantic User-model (that again has a rank property).

Is there another option, or did I make a mistake in my attempts so far?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Reading the caveats section solved almost a day of pounding my head against the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to use a window function (row_number() OVER) in the WHERE clause, which is not allowed in SQL. Instead, you can use a subquery to first calculate the rankings and then filter based on the rankings:

```
 subq = db.session.query(User.id.label('id'), func.row_number().over(order_by=desc(User.points)).label('rank')).subquery()
results = db.session.query(User, subq.c.rank)\
    .join(subq, User.id == subq.c.id)\
    .filter(subq.c.rank < 10)\
    .order_by(subq.c.rank)\
    .all()
```

Here, we first create a subquery to calculate the rankings using the row_number() window function, and then join this subquery with the original User table on the id column. We can then filter based on the calculated rankings in the subquery and order the results by the rank. Note that we also use the label() function to give the subquery columns meaningful names (id and rank) so we can refer to them in the main query.

Comment: Thank you, that works. However same as the approach using add_columns, this returns tuples of <User, rank>. I suppose there is no way of having the computed rank as part of the User-model and populate it during the query? I have also tried storing the rank as a column_property couldn't get the window function right

Comment: No p, check my answer as correct

Comment: It is possible: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/columns.html#orm-queryguide-with-expression